# Key matrix redundant in Transformer language models?

Tags: nlp, transformer-model

Simple implementations of Transformer language models such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCc8FmEb1nY) define 3 matrices K,Q,V to compute keys, queries and values. However matrices K and Q are never used separately: all Transformer computations form their product `Q^t K`. So I wonder why not learn this product matrix directly instead of splitting it into 2 matrices K and Q.

Part of the answer may come from the size of K and Q, which is `d -> n`, where d is the dimension of the token embeddings and n is the dimension of keys and queries. The size of `Q^t K` is `d -> d`. So learning K and Q separately means optimizing `2*n*d` parameters, whereas learning the product `Q^t K` is `d*d` parameters. The only useful splitting I see is when `n <= d/2`, because that's less parameters to optimize. But at the limit case `n = d/2`, the rank of the product matrix `Q^t K` is `d/2`, which is very degenerate. With the same number of parameters `d^2`, we could learn an unconstrained square matrix. That might learn more flexible and subtle patterns in the training data.

In the [Attention is all you need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) paper, base model page 9, we see d = 512 and n = 64, so the product matrix `Q^t K` does have degenerate rank. Is reducing the number of parameters the true and unique intent here? Is there a theoretical justification that these degenerate ranks help natural language processing?